# C# Multiple Lines in Tool Tip

Tags: c#, string, list, tooltip

I am doing this (value is a list of strings):

```
protected override bool _setValue(object value)
{
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    toolTip.Content = string.Join("\r\n", value);
    return true;
}
```

When I hover over the item that has the tool tip, it displays "System.Generic.List'1[System.String]"

So apparently the string.Join() is returning a list object, not a string.

How do I make the tool tip display multiple lines of text?

Comment: Who have added `function` keyword to C#? ;)

Comment: The method needs to accept `object[] values` or `IEnumerable<T> values` or cast `value` to one of the possible types. See the parameters for String.Join: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev I was just trying to show an example for what I need. That wasn't actually in the code.

Comment: @SpencerRue Yes, I guess that. I have just joked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type of `String.Join` method is string not List. You need to call your object type to List to get the right answer. Other wise its compiler is just using `value.ToString()` and value is an object not List. Just tried it

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new List<string>
            {
                "Test 1",
                "test 2"
            };
            WillPrintCorrect(items);
            WillPrintWrong(items);
            BestWay(items);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static void WillPrintCorrect(object value)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,(List<string>)value));
        }

        public static void WillPrintWrong(object value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, value));
        }

        public static void BestWay(List<string> value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, value));
    }
```

Comment: This explains the problem, but does not give a solution.

Comment: It do both, if u look clearly. I am casting it "List<string>" and it works fine after that.

Comment: really, do you understand what I am trying to do here? check your method, your parameter type is Object. So When you passing it a List, it converts it into a list.  exactly what I am doing by casting a List<string> to object. I am going to change exactly how you doing it.

Comment: @GauravSharma I had to wait 5 minutes until I could accept answer.

Comment: I am hoping this method is not real code. There are couple of issues in writing method like this.

Comment: @GauravSharma This function comes is in a derived class of a base class which does not know anything about the data types. The derived classes are the only place that know about specific data types.